# How to update text with track changes in MS Word add-in

Tags: ms-word, office-js

For my Word add-in, I'd like to edit the text of the Word document with track changes.

It seems that one solution could be:

1. Use `getooxml` to get XML representation
2. Update the XML representation as desired with `ins` and `del` tags
3. Use `insertooxml` to update the Word document

Is there a better way of doing this?  I'm concerned about accidentally corrupting the Word document.

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no way to access the Track Changes feature with the Office JavaScript APIs.You can vote for the suggestion at [Add change](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/13649829-add-change-tracking-api) tracking API.

Also if you can explain "edit the text of the Word document with track changes." ,you want to edit or track ?